# How to handle large Sets of categorical Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I'm a beginner in machine learning. i have a large Data Set with lots of categorical data. The data is nominal. I want to apply algorithmns like SVM and decision tree with Python and scikit-learn to to find patterns in the data.

My problem is, it that i dont know how to best handle that kind of data. I read a lot about One-Hot Encoding. The examples are all quite easy, like with three different colors. In my data there are around 30 different categorical features. And in those features are around 200 different "values".
If i use simple One-Hot Encoding the data frame gets really big and i can hardly use any algorithm on the data because i run out of ram.

So whats the best approach here? Use a sql database for the encoded tables? How is this done in the "real" world?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Have you familiar with the concept of sparse matrices? There are several libraries that handle them and could help you save some space. Depending on which library for machine learning you currently use look for methods and class that involve sparse matrices. Of course, another solution could be to reduce dimensionality as suggested in Rocky Li's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143289/4691498)

Comment: thanks @gvgramazio, i was not familiar with sparce matrices. i will  read into it!

Answer (score 1):

Sklearn does not handle categorical features with decision trees and random forest - it requires them to be converted to one-hot encoded columns. Realistically though, there are a slightly better alternative:

[image]

This is called binary encoding which will separate all type, much better than numerical encoding for categorical columns.

Another way to approach this problem is using `clipping`. The idea of clipping is to only register the largest categories, e.g. All categories that account for 5%+ of all values, and encode the rest as 'tail'. This is another method to reduce dimensionality.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, this problem has brought a huge new realization to me.

First of all, it is important to differentiate your categorical data based on their content; a.k.a. `nominal` or `ordinal` data.

Nominal data stands for any kind of categorical data, which has no ranking or sequential relationship between different values, i.e. milk, egg, bread, and so on.

On the other hand, ordinal data refers to values with a sequential relationship, i.e., primary school, high school, college, master, and so on (in other words when you assign primary school 1, you assign high school 2 since there is a ranking).

Afterward, you can use many encoding approaches, for the detailed explanation you can use here :
[Smarter ways for encoding categorical data](https://towardsdatascience.com/smarter-ways-to-encode-categorical-data-for-machine-learning-part-1-of-3-6dca2f71b159)